# Curl GET message hangs my console

Tags: curl, github

I'm trying to execute simple curl get message against github, example taken from:

```
https://developer.github.com/v3/
```

So, the message I send is:
curl -i https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs
but this, isn't returning any response, just hangs my console.
Any idea as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to set certificates location for https IF you try it with the -k option does it still hang?

Comment: @Mihai Hi, thank you for your answer. No, indeed, with the -k option it doesn't hang, it simply returns '[ ]'. Could you please point me to some links with documentation explaining the process of setting certificate's location, thank you